# Keep Leading Zero In Export

Tags: powershell-4.0

I am using powershell to run a sql query and export to a csv file.  Process works great, but it is dropping a leading 0 in one of my columns.  Field type in SQL Server is a varchar (not an option to change it unfortunately), and here is my syntax.  Is it possible to continue to use my powershell export process and keep the leading zero?

```
$GoodSyntax = "Select * From tableunknown"
$extractFile = "C:\Test.csv"
Execute-SQLquery 
if (Execute-SQLquery $GoodSyntax) 

Function Execute-SQLquery {
  param ($GoodSyntax)

$server = "Server01"
$database = "database01"    
$connectionTemplate = "Data Source={0};Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog={1};"
$connectionString = [string]::Format($connectionTemplate, $server, $database)
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$command.CommandText = $QueryString
$command.Connection = $connection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $command
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$rowCount = $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
    $DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-Csv $extractFile -NoTypeInformation

    $connection.Close()
```

EDIT ---
Upon further examination, and opening my CSV file in a raw editor like notepad++ the leading zeros are their!  They are just dropped when you attempt to view the file in Excel.  So Excel is the culprit here.

Comment: @VisualMicro -- I am opening the CSV in Excel once the procedure has executed and their is no leading 0.  However if I run the SQL Query directly in SSMS the leading zero is their.

Comment: Yes this is what Excel does with numbers unless you do some very messy things. It is not the sql that is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never seen sql drop any data from varchar. How are you testing this? Maybe the problem is not in the sql but in whatever you use to look at the data.

I know that Excel does remove leading 0's because it tries to be clever and convert chars to numbers but sql does not.

Try viewing the result of `$DataSet.GetXml()` which will show the raw data more clearly.

```
$connection.Close()

$DataSet.GetXml()
```

Update: Excel strips the leading 0's and is confusing you. The sql data is correct.

*How to specify formatting when opening a csv file in excel*

http://www.upenn.edu/computing/da/bo/webi/qna/iv_csvLeadingZeros.html

Normally I create an xml/html file from the data. Excel will open it and supports various attributes with the data that control formatting, but its messy.

Comment: At what point in my syntax would I add the line suggested above?

Comment: After the end of the code above you have the DataSet

Comment: Is their a way to keep Excel showing that leading zero with my above syntax?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like:

```
$a = "1000"
$a = $a.substring($a.length - 3, 37)
```

Ref.  - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176945.aspx

Comment: The .csv file is stripping the leading zero, is their some powershell syntax that will allow .csv to keep the leading zero?